# Pass created object as argument, from inside that object, C++

Tags: c++

I am facing the following problem. I have the following classes, `Room` and `Reservation` . For `Reservation` class there is a function (`void Reservation :: rsrvRoomAssignment(Room* r)`) that assigns the `Room* rsrvRoom` member of `Reservation` class,  to a `Room` object.  I want though to call this class from inside the Room object but i have no clue on how to achieve that properly passing as argument the created object that runs the code.

The code describes the above:

Reservation.h

```
class Room;

class Reservation {
public:
    static int rsrvCode;
    string rsrvName;
    unsigned int rsrvDate;
    unsigned int rsrvNights;
    unsigned int rsrvPersons;
    Room* rsrvRoom;             // Room assigned to reservation.
    Reservation();
    ~Reservation();
    void rsrvRoomAssignment(Room*);

};
```

Reservation.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Reservation.h"

using namespace std;

/* 
    Constructor & Destructor 
*/

void Reservation :: rsrvRoomAssignment(Room* r){
    rsrvRoom=r;
}
```

Room.h

```
#include "Reservation.h"
class Room {
public:
    static unsigned int roomNumber;
    unsigned int roomCapacity;
    Reservation* roomAvailability[30];
    double roomPrice;
    Room();
    ~Room();
    bool roomReservationAdd(Reservation*);
};
```

Room.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Room.h"

using namespace std;

/*
    Constructor & destructor
*/

bool Room::roomReservationAdd(Reservation* r){
    /* some statement that returns flase */
    r->rsrvRoomAssignment(/* & of created object */); // This is the problem i described.
    return 1;
}
```

I am pretty new to OOP so there might be some more logical errors on the above snipsets, so don't be harsh :) .

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: `r->rsrvRoomAssignment(this->Room);`?? `Room` doesn't have a member called `Room`? Did you mean `r->rsrvRoomAssignment(this);`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The idea I am trying to describe with the comments on `Room.cpp`, is that I want to pass as an argument to `rsrvRoomAssignment` the created object of `Room` class that will call `r->rsrvRoomAssignment`

Comment: You shouldn't mess around with pointers in c++. If you need to pass a reference somewhere, rather use a reference parameter (`&`). Also post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem, all error messages included verbatim.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖI think you are misunderstanding me and it's my fault. I know that `this->Room` is wrong, and I only pasted it there to make understandable the nature of my question. I did it Since I am not familiar with many terms in OOP and in C++. My goal is only to describe the idea I am trying to implement.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖI made an edit to my post, since I think I wasn't making clear my issue. Thank you for pointing me to it!

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking too complicated. Why would you like to assign `Room` from `Reservation` and not just vice versa.

Comment: You might be interested in our [list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) for familiarising yourself with the terms better.

Comment: `void rsrvRoomAssignment(Room*);` expects an `Room*`, so passing `this` in `bool Room::roomReservationAdd(Reservation* r)` could solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inside a class method, `this` indicates the instance of the object calling it. In your case, when a room instance `X` calls `X.roomReservationAdd(r)`,
this points to the room instance `X`. 
Hence, you can simply call `r->rsrvRoomAssignment(this);`